# Rails 3.1 precompile assets error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting an unusual error when I run `rake assets:precompile`. I am using jruby 1.6.5.1, and the issue only occurs on one machine, but works fine on others.

```
[x@x someapp]$ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/x/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5.1/bin/jruby /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
partial character in source, but hit end near �\")&&  (k=/^[\\s\\xA0]+/,l=/[\\s\\xA0]+$/),h=e(c),c.addEventListener......
..............................
(in /home/x/someapp/cmeng/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
json/ext/Parser.java:249:in `parse'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/json-1.6.1-java/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/multi_json-1.0.3/lib/multi_json/engines/json_gem.rb:13:in `decode'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/multi_json-1.0.3/lib/multi_json.rb:65:in `decode'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/execjs-1.2.9/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:61:in `extract_result'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/execjs-1.2.9/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/execjs-1.2.9/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:40:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/execjs-1.2.9/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:26:in `exec'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/uglifier-1.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:95:in `compile'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:18:in `compress'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `js_compressor='
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:175:in `evaluate'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:172:in `evaluate'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:242:in `build_source'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:30:in `cache_hash'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:235:in `build_source'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:71:in `digest'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/asset.rb:95:in `digest_path'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:58:in `path_for'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/actionpack- 3.1.1/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:35:in `write_asset'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:21:in `compile'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:151:in `each_logical_path'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:139:in `each_file'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:129:in `each_entry'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:137:in `each_file'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:136:in `each_file'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:149:in `each_logical_path'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:52:in `internal_precompile'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:66:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/x/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/x/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in `load'
/home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/bin/rake:19:in `(root)'
```

If I remove the jQuery requires (jquery and jquery_ujs) in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, the precompile task succeeds.

I've traced the error to the jquery source file:

```
// IE doesn't match non-breaking spaces with \s
if ( rnotwhite.test( "\xA0" ) ) {
    trimLeft = /^[\s\xA0]+/;
    trimRight = /[\s\xA0]+$/;
}
```

Could the \xA0 character be causing this error? Or is it something else?

Thanks.

Comment: I can get around it by just commenting out that block of offending code, but it would be good to know what the cause is.

Comment: I'm having this error on the same line in jQuery. What's weird is that deploying to my stage environment, with the same assets, same version of jRuby, and the same everything else (at least, it's supposed to be!), doesn't hit this problem--only deploying to production hits this!

Comment: I suspect that this problem is due to some setting of the Java running on your/my staging/production servers--running the precompile on OS X on the same version of jRuby has no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get asset precompilation to work with jQuery 1.7.2 under jRuby 1.6.7 by switching from the `:uglifier` compressor (the default) to the `:closure` compiler. (I also tried the `:yui` compiler, but it's apparently not compatible with jRuby--it wants to use `fork`, which jRuby doesn't want to provide.)